# React import problem, 'Module not found: Can't resolve' while import package wechaty

Tags: node.js, reactjs, wechaty

I'm new to nodejs and react. In my project, I use a package "wechaty". And it works fine when my project is a pure nodejs.

Then when I try to integrate "wechaty" with react, it failed to compile and report errors.

// Code in App.js

> ```
> import { WechatyBuilder, ScanStatus, log} from "wechaty"
> ```

When I run npm start/yarn start, the error message appears

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'wechaty' in
> 'D:\git\chat-client\src'

I guess it may be because there is no 'module' field in the package.json of 'wechaty', so I add that field.

> "module": "./dist/esm/src/mods/mod.js",

The exact problem do disappeared. But it still cannot resolve sub modules.

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./node_modules/wechaty/dist/esm/src/mods/mod.js Module not found:
> Can't resolve 'wechaty-puppet/helpers' in
> 'D:\git\chat-client\node_modules\wechaty\dist\esm\src\mods'
> Compiling... Failed to compile.

Even worse is that 'wechaty' has many dependence packages, and all the dependence packages have the same problem.

**Here follows the package.json of 'wechaty':**

```
    {
  "name": "wechaty",
  "version": "1.0.6",
  "description": "Wechaty is a RPA SDK for Chatbot Makers.",
  "type": "module",

  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/esm/src/mods/mod.js",
      "require": "./dist/cjs/src/mods/mod.js"
    },
    "./impls": {
      "import": "./dist/esm/src/mods/impls.js",
      "require": "./dist/cjs/src/mods/impls.js"
    },
    "./users": {
      "import": "./dist/esm/src/mods/users.js",
      "require": "./dist/cjs/src/mods/uses.js"
    }
  },
  "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "users": [
        "./dist/esm/src/mods/users.d.ts"
      ],
      "impls": [
        "./dist/esm/src/mods/impls.d.ts"
      ]
    }
  },
  "types": "./dist/esm/src/mods/mod.d.ts",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16",
    "npm": ">=7"
  },
  "wechaty": {
    "DEFAULT_PORT": 8080,
    "DEFAULT_PROTOCOL": "io|0.0.1",
    "DEFAULT_APIHOST": "api.chatie.io"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && tsc -p tsconfig.cjs.json",
    "changelog": "docker run -it --rm -e CHANGELOG_GITHUB_TOKEN -v \"$(pwd)\":/usr/local/src/your-app ferrarimarco/github-changelog-generator -u wechaty -p wechaty && sed -i'.bak' /greenkeeper/d CHANGELOG.md && sed -i'.bak' /Snyk/d CHANGELOG.md && sed -i'.bak' '/An in-range update of/d' CHANGELOG.md && node --no-warnings --loader=ts-node/esm scripts/sort-contributiveness.ts < CHANGELOG.md > CHANGELOG.new.md 2>/dev/null && cat CHANGELOG.md >> CHANGELOG.new.md && mv CHANGELOG.new.md CHANGELOG.md",
    "check-node-version": "check-node-version --node \">= 16\"",
    "clean": "shx rm -fr dist/*",
    "coverage": "nyc report --reporter=lcov",
    "demo": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--no-warnings --loader=ts-node/esm\" node examples/ding-dong-bot.ts",
    "dist": "npm-run-all clean build dist:commonjs",
    "dist:commonjs": "jq -n \"{ type: \\\"commonjs\\\" }\" > dist/cjs/package.json",
    "docs": "bash -x scripts/generate-docs.sh",
    "doctor": "npm run check-node-version && node --no-warnings --loader=ts-node/esm bin/doctor.ts",
    "io-client": "node --no-warnings --loader=ts-node/esm bin/io-client.ts",
    "lint:es": "eslint --ignore-pattern node_modules/ --ignore-pattern fixtures/ \"{bin,examples,src,scripts,tests}/**/*.ts\"",
    "lint:md": "markdownlint README.md",
    "lint:sh": "bash -n bin/*.sh",
    "lint:ts": "tsc --isolatedModules --noEmit",
    "lint": "npm-run-all check-node-version lint:es lint:ts lint:sh lint:md",
    "puppet-install": "node --no-warnings --loader=ts-node/esm bin/puppet-install.ts",
    "sloc": "sloc bin examples scripts src tests --details --format cli-table --keys total,source,comment && sloc bin examples scripts src tests",
    "start": "npm run demo",
    "test:pack": "bash -x scripts/npm-pack-testing.sh",
    "test:shell": "shellcheck bin/*.sh scripts/*.sh",
    "test:unit": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--no-warnings --loader=ts-node/esm\" TAP_TIMEOUT=60 tap \"src/**/*.spec.ts\" \"tests/**/*.spec.ts\"",
    "test": "npm run lint && nyc npm run test:unit && npm run sloc",
    "typedoc": "bash scripts/typedoc.sh"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/wechaty/wechaty.git"
  },
  "bin": {
    "wechaty-doctor": "dist/esm/bin/doctor.js",
    "wechaty-io-client": "dist/esm/bin/io-client.js",
    "wechaty-puppet-install": "dist/esm/bin/puppet-install.js",
    "wechaty-version": "dist/esm/bin/version.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ai",
    "bot",
    "chatbot",
    "chatie",
    "conversational",
    "framework",
    "robot",
    "rpa",
    "sdk",
    "wechat",
    "wecom",
    "wxwork",
    "lark",
    "TikTok",
    "weixin",
    "whatsapp",
    "微信"
  ],
  "author": {
    "name": "Huan LI (李卓桓)",
    "email": "zixia@zixia.net",
    "url": "https://linkedin.com/in/zixia/"
  },
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/wechaty/wechaty/issues"
  },
  "funding": {
    "type": "opencollective",
    "url": "https://opencollective.com/wechaty"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/wechaty/",
  "dependencies": {
    "clone-class": "^1.0.2",
    "cockatiel": "^2.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "json-rpc-peer": "^0.17.0",
    "open-graph": "^0.2.6",
    "state-switch": "^1.1.15",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "wechaty-puppet": "^1.0.1",
    "wechaty-puppet-service": "^1.0.1",
    "ws": "^8.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chatie/eslint-config": "^1.0.3",
    "@chatie/git-scripts": "^0.6.2",
    "@chatie/semver": "^0.4.7",
    "@chatie/tsconfig": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/glob": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/open-graph": "^0.2.2",
    "@types/raven": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "@types/ws": "^8.2.0",
    "check-node-version": "^4.1.0",
    "coveralls": "^3.1.1",
    "glob": "^7.2.0",
    "jsdoc-to-markdown": "^7.1.0",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "qrcode-terminal": "^0.12.0",
    "raven": "^2.6.4",
    "sloc": "^0.2.1",
    "typed-emitter": "^1.4.0",
    "typedoc": "^1.0.0-dev.4 ",
    "wechaty-puppet-mock": "^1.0.1",
    "wechaty-puppet-padlocal": "^0.4.2"
  },
  "files": [
    "bin/",
    "dist/",
    "src/"
  ],
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public",
    "tag": "latest"
  },
  "collective": {
    "type": "opencollective",
    "url": "https://opencollective.com/wechaty"
  },
  "git": {
    "scripts": {
      "pre-push": "npx git-scripts-pre-push"
    }
  }
}
```

**Here follows the ./dist/esm/src/mods/mod.js**

```
export { WechatyBuilder, } from '../wechaty-builder.js';
export * as type from 'wechaty-puppet/types';
export * as payload from 'wechaty-puppet/payloads';
export * as helper from 'wechaty-puppet/helpers';
export * as impl from './impls.js';
export * as user from './users.js';
export * from './users.js';
export { ScanStatus, } from 'wechaty-puppet/types';
export { log, config, qrcodeValueToImageUrl, VERSION, } from '../config.js';
export { IoClient, } from '../io-client.js';
//# sourceMappingURL=mod.js.map
```

Here follows package.js of my own project:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "wechaty": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. I'm the author of Wechaty and let's discuss on GitHub at https://github.com/wechaty/wechaty/issues/2305 first, and we can post the final solution as the answer back to SO.